# Python dynamic functions from strings

Tags: python, python-2.7, metaprogramming, dynamic-function

I came across few related answers but not what I want.

Here is the code I have now:

```
code_str = """
print "this is my global x = " + x
print "And another line is done"
"""

x = 'mystery'

func_template = lambda p: None

func_template.__code__ = compile(code_str, '<string>', 'exec')
func_template() # this executes fine and also has access to x, which i do need.
# func_template('param') # This raises: TypeError: <module>() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

Some background; The code_str will be coming from a database, and I need to store lots of functions in a dict so I can call any one by name, like below:

```
all_funcs = {}

# Assuming db_result returns a list of name, code tuples from the databse

for name, code in db_result:
    all_funcs[name] = my_compile(code)
```

I want to then just call the needed function with the arguments I want if I know the name:

```
result = all_funcs[by_name](arg1, arg2)
```

**Edit:**  database is trusted, so I do not need to santize or worry about malicious code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you replace the `__code__` object of a lambda, you basically redefine the function. The new argcount is determined by `__code__.co_argcount`, so it doesnt't matter which or how many arguments the lambda took before.

If you want to pass a parameter to your compiled code, you could try to `eval` your code object directly, passing your parameter in the `locals` dictionaray:

```
code_str = """
print "this is my global x = " + x
print "And another line is done"
print param
"""

compiled = compile(code_str, "<string>", "exec")
func_template = lambda p=None: eval(compiled, globals(), {'param': p})

x = "1"
func_template()
func_template("2")
```

This way you can obviously only pass keyword arguments, it's not possible to use positional arguments. You could also use

```
func_template = lambda **kwargs: eval(compiled, globals(), **kwargs)
```

to pass the keyword arguments given to your function directly.

If you need a return value from your function, then you'd need to compile the code in `'eval'` mode instead, which means you have to limit your code to an expressions and can't have statements.